# HighCharts moving xAxis label (dates) to between two series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By default, the date labels are at the very bottom of the chart. I have several series charts but want the date labels to be beneath the first one. I've looked all over the APIs and searched all over but don't see an option for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Recreate your example on jsfiddle.net as live demo.

Comment: You need to be much more specific. Provide an illustration or example of what you are trying to do, and details of what is not working.